# Git-LFS add filetypes (without doubling repo size)

Tags: git, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree, git-lfs

I have a big repo on GitLab.com (8GB) with some assets (textures, etc). I decided to use git lfs for the sometimes above 50MB files.

I started with
`git lfs migrate import --include="*.png"`
and did
`git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all`
`git gc --prune=now`
and tracked the filetype (track, commit .gitattributes, push)

The problem is that my repository size nearly doubled and I can't push new content, not even the .gitattributes because of the 10GB sizelimit

How can I tell git that git lfs has already tracked the .png files and that the original versions in the repo can be deleted? (I thought that migrate would exactly do that, but it doesn’t)

Update: I did a test-repo with just 1 bigger file. And the outcome is the same. I have doubled the repo size, because the file seems to be in the normal repo and lfs at the same time. In gitlab.com it is shown with a lfs tag tough.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Git LFS will migrate only the current reference (usually the current branch). If you want to migrate your entire repository, which is almost always what you want to do, you need to use the `--everything` option to `git lfs migrate import` so that it will traverse all branches and tags.

Note that if your repository has a tag pointing to another tag, which is uncommon but sometimes occurs, that tag will not be migrated in the current version.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. But I was already testing it with a single branch repo (master only).

Comment: Ok, so. Your suggested command created a new commit history. But I couldn't find a way to delete the old master branch, so I am still stuck with the double size of what is actually in the repo. What would be the next steps to handle this new commit history?

Comment: In what way do you still have the old `master` branch? How are you detecting that?

Comment: I'm using sourcetree. Seeing it in the branchview. Giving the new branch a name. Then I used a special command to merge the two branches with unconnected histories. Now I have 1 branch, but it still has the big file size.

Comment: I'm not familiar with SourceTree. The `git lfs migrate import --everything` should have rewritten the entire history, including all branches, not created a new one. Can you edit your question to show the output of `git for-each-ref`?

Comment: I will have to create a new repo and do the testing again, I will edit/post tomorrow.

Comment: So, I retried it with a new repo. And the `git lfs migrate import --everything` does rewrite the history in a new branch. My master branch was protected though, so I could not delete the old history, what kept the repo size big. I will go for a third try soon and hopefully be able to use git-lfs for some of my repos.

Comment: be careful, this (running `git lfs migrate import --everything`) screwed up my entire git repo. Make sure to make a copy before trying this.